# html5 drag and drop; on dragend; source table scrolls back to top

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've got two tables.  The source table has several thousand rows and a vertical scrollbar to move through them.  I've got HTML5 drag-and-drop setup to allow dragging a row from the source table and dropping it on the target table, at which point it copies the contents into the target table and refreshes the target table's div.  Everything's hunky dory so far.

Upon the drop, however, the source table's scrolling rolls back to the top.  I'd like to keep that from happening so the user can work within a section of the long table, e.g. they scroll down to row 527, drag/drop it over to the target table, and then they can immediately drag/drop row 528 next because the source table scroll hasn't moved.

I've got event.preventDefault() in my dragend handler but that's obviously not what I need.

I'm assuming the source table is getting rerendered...but it shouldn't be...the ajax call to reload the target table only refreshes that div.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Several thousand rows in html table?

Comment: Can you provide your code? For "several thousand rows", you can mark it in your code as `here is thousands of <td>`